What is the simplest way to detect internet connectivity on macOS with a script?
I know I can use ping or nc, but macOS itself must be storing the state of internet connection somewhere right?
For example, when you connect to Wifi, with no internet, macOS gives an indication (in Control Center) that it has connected to the Wifi but there is no internet. That's the kind of use case I want to verify by determining internet connectivity:

Can that information be accessed through Terminal or by a script to determine if an internet connection exists?

Can you specify if you want to check this on a generic machine at a generic location, or specifically for a single machine in a place where you have knowledge of the network layout?

@PaulJanssens It's for a script that will run on many machines, not specific to any locatioon.

I don't think macOS stores whether it's "connected to the Internet". "Connected to the Internet" is most usually a shorthand for "I can load that website". That is, the same Internet access can be seen as "working" or "not working", depending on your use case. For example, if several services, let's say time synchronization (port 123) and DNS (port 53) are not reachable, but web access (port 443) works, is the Mac connected to the Internet? I'd recommend that you simply check if nc can reach some widely used service (the Google DNS servers, or a popular website or websites of your choosing).

Maybe you can expand what you mean by "Internet connectivy"?

@jaume When you connect to Wifi, with no internet, macOS gives an indication (in the system tray) that it has connected to the Wifi but there is no internet. That's the kind of use case I want to verify, by determining "internet connectivity".  There are  a lot of macOS services that depends on, and activates when a Mac connects to the internet. It doesn't make sense that all of these services try to determine internet connectivity on their own. Rather, macOS must have one service to check for internet connectivity that all of these other Apple and non-apple services can use too.

macOS may as well send an event to „interested“ applications if network connectivity changes, without actually keeping this state (as others have said, keeping a state would be rather unreliable). What makes a simple ping not useful in your case?

@nohillside Yes, it may be a system event. In which case, my question can be - how can a script register itself to receive this event? As for avoiding ping (or other options), I just don't want to reinvent the wheel - there must be some existing OS API or mechanism already for this and I would prefer to use that.

What is the context here, what does your script do when there is a network, or there isn’t? We might miss part of the picture here.

@nohillside It's meant as an always running toolkit to do various admin tasks. If there is no internet connection, then some tasks / options that need it should not be shown (greyed out) .

Thanks for your feedback, I've expanded your post to mention how Control Center displays information about Internet connectivity. As for network connectivity changes, I can't imagine how a script could receive a system event (the API seems to be Swift-only, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network/nwpathmonitor), but you can use a polling mechanism in your script, for example by regularly running networksetup -listnetworkserviceorder and networksetup -getinfo networkservice, and comparing the previous and current results (see man networksetup for details).

Caveat: I don't know how macOS determines the No Internet Connection message it displays in Control Center.
However, I can think of two three tests you could run from the command line that would tell you the status of your Internet Connection:
1. networkQuality (note the capital 'Q' !); ref: man networkQuality
A bit of an oddball command, this one was clearly created by Apple :)  If you run the command bare (no options), it takes a few seconds to complete, but as a bonus you get speed tests for uplink & downlink, latency and something called "responsiveness". I'll leave it to you to review the manual (man networkQuality) & read the other document to customize the command to suit your particular needs.
% networkQuality
==== SUMMARY ====
Uplink capacity: 44.324 Mbps
Downlink capacity: 155.511 Mbps
Responsiveness: Low (54 RPM)
Idle Latency: 18.250 milliseconds

NOTE: networkQuality was released with macOS 12; Monterey.
2. dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com; ref: man dig
This is the one I typically use... if it returns an IP address, it (usually) means I (my mac) am (is) connected to the Internet.
% dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
126.55.123.171

3. iperf3 - ooh la la (French origin, open source)
My #2 (dig) doesn't seem to work for the OP, and his macOS doesn't have networkQuality, so after some research & testing I'll add  iperf to the list. iperf is available through MacPorts (my choice), HomeBrew or via the sponsor's GitHub site.
iperf3 is a bit different from the other tools here as it's a client-server app. However, you don't have to set up your own server, as public servers are available. It's also supported by the Lawrence Berkeley National Laboratory affiliate Energy Sciences Network; IOW it's a stable & dependable [ :) ] application.
It's use is straightforward, and it comes with an excellent manual (man iperf3):
% iperf3 -c ping.online.net
Connecting to host ping.online.net, port 5201
[  7] local 192.168.1.209 port 57346 connected to 51.158.1.21 port 5201
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  7]   0.00-1.00   sec  6.38 MBytes  53.3 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   1.00-2.01   sec  16.5 MBytes   138 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   2.01-3.00   sec  20.8 MBytes   174 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   3.00-4.00   sec  19.6 MBytes   165 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   4.00-5.01   sec  22.2 MBytes   186 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   5.01-6.01   sec  20.4 MBytes   171 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   6.01-7.00   sec  19.5 MBytes   164 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   7.00-8.01   sec  22.1 MBytes   185 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   8.01-9.01   sec  21.0 MBytes   176 Mbits/sec                  
[  7]   9.01-10.00  sec  20.9 MBytes   175 Mbits/sec                  
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate
[  7]   0.00-10.00  sec   189 MBytes   159 Mbits/sec                  sender
[  7]   0.00-10.11  sec   189 MBytes   156 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf Done.

And here's what a "no Internet" output looks like (obtained by disabling the WAN interface on my firewall):
% iperf3 -c ping.online.net
iperf3: error - unable to connect to server - server may have stopped running or use a different port, firewall issue, etc.: Network is unreachable


The command networkQuality isn't available on macOS Catalina?

@Seamus Didn't know about networkQuality, great contribution.

@sfxedit I'm afraid it's indeed not available on Catalina. According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Monterey#Changes) and to the Network Quality Server GitHub project (https://github.com/network-quality/server), networkQuality was first released in macOS 12 Monterey.

No, the dig command doesn't work as I get no result. And, as I stated in the Q and comments, I am not interested in such tools. I am looking for something "built-in" and less resource intensive - after all, you can't keep pinging some server every few seconds, 24x7 to check for the internet.

@sfxedit You shouldn't be using ping anyway, my experience is that ICMP is often blocked. As mentioned above, querying DNS or checking if a popular website is reachable is the way to go. For example, run dig +short www.google.com and check whether it returns any output. If it does, the DNS query was successful and the computer is online, or use nc -w 1 www.google.com 443 and check that the exit status is "0". In that case, the computer is online. Use the "$?" shell variable to query the exit status, see https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters for details.

@sfxedit I understand you prefer a "built-in" solution, but it's unclear how the OS mechanism for checking Internet connectivity works, and running "dig" or "nc" is not resource intensive at all.
